# Does Callout work with BubbleChart?

Tags: plotting

I've tried to evaluate the following:

```
BubbleChart[{Callout[{1, 1, 1}, "Hey!", 1]}]
```

And do not see any label added to the disk.

Is `Callout` meant to work with `BubbleChart` or it is not yet supported?

I use Mathematica 11.0 on Win7.

Comment: In the documentation for [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) (Details and Options), `Callout` is NOT one of the 11 wrappers listed that can be used for chart elements.

Comment: Right. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does now in v11.1. The automatic position for Callout will try to put labels inside the bubble if possible, otherwise find a position that doesn't overlap.

[image]